# I need to ask my web site's user a Yes/ No question. in javaScript

Tags: javascript, dialog

I need to ask my web site's user a Yes/ No question. Currently I use JavaScript's confirm() function.
The return value is true (OK) or false (CANCEL).
The word CANCEL is misleading. I want to have the buttons say Yes/ No instead.
How can I do it? i m using php..**Code should run on both IE & Firefox**

Answer (score 4):

With HTML:

```
<div id="yesNo">
  <p>Press Yes or No</p>
</div>
```

and [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog):

```
$('#yesNo').dialog({
  modal: true,      
  buttons: { 
   "Yes": function() { alert("Yes"); } 
   "No": function() { alert("No"); } 
  } 
});
```

Or use standard confirm dialog (but it will have Ok, Cancel buttons):

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  alert("Yes");
} else {
  alert("No");
}
```

Comment: do we need to download this 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/', to use your example ?

Comment: Yes. The sample relies on the dialog from jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [JQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly cannot rephrase the question as OK/Cancel, then you will need to create your own dialog in a div or something and 'pop it up' to the user. (You could also create a dialog as a page and then use a popup window to display it as a real native OS modal dialog, but this is perhaps more annoying.)

Unfortunately, javascript's browser built in dialogs are pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). It has a nice dialog (including modal). As well as it have many other nice feature you may need in your webapp.
Of course you can paraphrase your question for OK/Cancel answer. But i think UI library is your friend.